# Non-decidable $\Pi^0_1$ (effectively closed) classes

Tags: logic, computability, baire-category

Are there non-decidable $\Pi^0_1$ (effectively closed) classes?  According to a draft of *Effectively closed sets* by Cenzer and Remmel, the class
$$
P = \{ 0^n1^\omega \mid n \in B\}
$$
is a non-decidable $\Pi^0_1$ class, where $B \subset \omega$ is a non-computable co-c.e. set.

According to the book,  $P \subseteq \omega^{\omega}$ is a $\Pi^0_1$ class if there exists a computable tree $T \subseteq \omega^{<\omega}$ that is passed through exactly by the paths in $P$, i.e., $[T] = P$, and it is decidable, if $T_P$ is computable, where $T_P = \{\sigma \in \omega^{<\omega} \mid P \cap I(\sigma) \neq 0\}$ and $I(\sigma) = \{ x \in \omega^\omega \mid \sigma \prec x\}$.

However, I "proved" that, in general, $T_P$ is the set $\{x \upharpoonright n \mid x \in P, n \in \omega\}$; $[T_P] = P$ for closed $P$; and that if $[T] = P$, $T_P = T$, which deny the existence of non-decidable $\Pi^0_1$ classes.

Is it possible for you to point out counterexamples to the three claims I "proved"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said, "If $[T] = P$ then $T_P = T$". Consider $T = \{ \langle\rangle, \langle 0 \rangle \} \cup \{ \langle 1^n \rangle : n \in \omega\}$. Then $T$ is a computable tree, $P = [T]$ is a one-point set and thus closed, and $T_P \not = T$.  That is a counterexample of the kind you asked for. These counterexamples all come from trees with dead ends.

In general, the set that is called $T_P$ is the set of "extendible nodes" of $T$. Let's call it $E(T)$ for now:
$$
E(T) = \{ \sigma \in T : (\exists x \in [T])[ \sigma \prec x] \}
$$

An easy fact is that if $[T] \not = \emptyset$ and $E(T)$ is computable then $[T]$ has a computable member. The construction of the member is simple: under these assumptions $\langle \rangle \in E(T)$, and for all $\sigma \in E(T)$ at least one of the children of $\sigma$ is in $E(T)$, so we can build a computable sequence $\sigma_i$ where $\sigma_0 = \langle\rangle$ and $\sigma_{i+1}$ is the leftmost child of $\sigma_i$ that is in $E(T)$. Then $x = \bigcup \sigma_i$ is in $[T]$.   So another way to find non-decidable $\Pi^0_1$ classes is to take classes with no computable members, e.g. the $\Pi^0_1$ class of all completions of Peano arithmetic.

We can verify that the example from Cenzer and Remmel is correct.  Actually, the way they wrote the $\Pi^0_1$ class is a little odd. The point $0^\omega$ must also be in this class, because $B$ is infinite and the class is closed. So the class is really $\{0^\omega\} \cup \{0^n1^\omega : n \in B\} = \operatorname{cl}\{0^n1^\omega : n \in B\}$.  Let's call this class $C$.

Given $n$, the only real extending $0^n1$ that *could* be in $C$ is $0^n1^\omega$. So for each $n$ we have that $0^n1$ is an extendible node if and only if $n$ is in our non-decidable set $B$, which means that if the set of extendible nodes is computable then so is $B$.  The assumption that $B$ is $\Pi^0_1$ is just so that the class $C$ is $\Pi^0_1$

For this particular $\Pi^0_1$ class $C$ from the previous paragraph, the tree 
$$T_C = \{ x \upharpoonright n : x \in C, n \in \omega\}$$
is not computable.  Nevertheless, this class is of the form $[T]$ for some computable $T$, which is defined as follows. $\sigma \in T$ if $\sigma = 0^n$ for some $n$, or if $\sigma = 0^n1^m$ and $n$ has not been enumerated out of $B$ within $m$ time-steps under some fixed r.e. enumeration of the complement of $B$. This is a computable definition, and we can verify that it gives a tree $T$ with $[T] = C$.

Comment: Is it possible for you to elaborate on "The assumption that $B$ is $\Pi^0_1$ is just so that the class $C$ is $\Pi^0_1$"?  (By the way, the book contains the definition for $P \in \omega^\omega$ being $\Pi^0_1$ and that of $P$ being a $\Pi^0_1$ class.  I don't know they are the same, but if not, the terminology is quite unfortunate.)

Comment: If you took any other noncomputable set of naturals instead of $B$, and made the same sort of tree, the resulting tree would also have a noncomputable set of extendible nodes, but the tree itself would not be computable. To make a class in $\omega^\omega$ be the set of paths through a computable tree, as in the last paragraph, you essentially need to have an r.e. way to list the "dead ends" of the tree (which is not the same as the set of non-extendible nodes). For that to be possible, the set $B$ needs to be co-r.e.

Comment: As for the overloading of the term "$\Pi^0_1$", it can refer to: a subset of $\omega$, a subset of $2^\omega$, a subset of $\omega^\omega$, an element of $2^\omega$, an element of $\omega^\omega$, a formula in the language of Peano arithmetic, or a formula in the language of second-order arithmetic.  The concepts are all closely related, and there is a method behind all the different terminology that is convenient once you understand it, but it is a significant learning curve at first.